# What's the chainstructure that mist is downloading?

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

What is the highest number of chain structures that I need to sync with? I'm currently on 10.08 million, and the block sync is stuck at 2,562,029.

Is this normal? The website telling me which block is the highest is not helpful, as my wallet is also downloading and syncing "chain structure" -- at 10.08 million now. I'm confused as to what the chain structure is and what the highest number is, to see if this is normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Mist uses [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) behind the scenes, and what you see when you see this message is Geth synchronizing. The *chain structure* is the Ethereum state trie; as of the time of this writing (May 2018) the state trie is about 150 million entries and a [full fast sync takes at least 8 hours](http://www.freekpaans.nl/2018/04/anatomy-geth-fast-sync/).

The state trie is defined in detail in the Ethereum [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

[This question has been asked before](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24045/stuck-on-downloading-chain-structure-it-keeps-increasing).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, the total chain structure is going at a little bit over 53 million entries.